# Javascript conflict with formbehavior.chosen in Joomla component

Tags: javascript, php, joomla, joomla3.0

I have to make some changes on the com_content component of Joomla.

I would like to add a listener to a select element like this :

```
mySelectList.addEventListener('change', function () {
        alert('message');
});
```

But when i select an item in my list, none message appears.

I noticed that, in my php file of the component (edit.php), when I remove this line :

```
JHtml::_('formbehavior.chosen', 'select');
```

Then my listener works ! But the css on select list element is removed too.

I would understand what is this formbehavior.chosen on select element, and if I remove it, would I have some changes (except the css style of my elements) ?

Hope I was understandable,

Thanks a lot

Comment: Use jQuery instead of Native JS

Comment: OK that resolves the problem, but that doesn't explain why this line makes these conflicts. But thanks, i can go on now :)